# Automate a process of steps that insert/add/replace somewhere in the middle

Tags: vim, macros

I've already learned how to do vim macros and I think it's an awesome way to improve productivity. But how do I automate something that has either insert (i or I), add (a or A) or replace (c or C) in the middle?

```
1. Disable line wrap
2. Add something to the end of the line (which is not defined yet)
3. Escape
4. Reactivate line wrap
```

Comment: can you make a small example show before/after  text?

Comment: line wrap is vim's capability to to send you to the next line while writing continuously in vim. That is an event which happens in insert mode. Hard to show it with before and after examples. If you never used line wrap then think about something else you want to do before you enter insert mode in whatever fashion and after you exit insert mode.

Comment: How can you automate anything if you don't know what you're doing beforehand? That is, you can't expect to automate something that is not deterministic. The macro cannot know whether you want `i,a` or `c` in the middle without you telling it explicitly and a priori.

Comment: @merlin2011 In other programming languages you use variables and functions for that. `deactivate_lw(); edit_method=ask_user_which_edit(); do_edit(edit_method); activate_lw()`. Why is this so hard to think that way? We are doing that kind of stuff all day, aren't we?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I thought when you said automate you wanted to do a bunch of these steps without direct user input and expected the macro to figure out whether to insert or append.

Comment: Ah maybe that's why nobody is answering. What I want is to be triggered by the macro for input, or simply adding that automated disabling/enabling for all the edit functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro that pastes a buffer, and fill that buffer before executing the macro.

Let's assume you have the following text:

```
This is a sample text
```

Now store

```
not
```

in buffer `o` (You can do this by writing it into a buffer, place the curor on it and use `"oyiw`)

Then lets assume you recorded a macro like this (or write this into a buffer and yank it into buffer `t`.)

```
0/sample^Mh"upi ^[
```

This places the cursor on the first character of the line, search for first occurrence of sample and then step back, insert whatever is in buffer `u` and then enter insert mode adds an additional space and exits insert mode.

Execute the macro using `@t`.

Hopefully you understand what i mean.

Comment: Could you add an example? Also it's unlikely that this will work with insert, add, and replace, right?

Comment: Btw it's nice but not a solution.